# How to enforce render table dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using bootstrap-vue b-table and b-pagination component. But since there two many records, so I'm using pagination call to backed, which means pass the paging information to the backend, only fetch corresponding records for each page.

Good thing: 
1. Data are passing correctly between backend and frontend.
2. Debug the frontend page through VUE debug tool, the properties of the b-table component are correct.

The problem:
The table is not rendering, it looks blank in the page, if I check the elements through chrome debugging tool. The elements (table body) for table container is empty.

A brief sample code :

```
  <b-container>
    <div v-if="guards_for_asyc_fetch_data_call">
      <b-row><b-col><h2>Title</h2></b-col></b-row>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-table
            :items="items"
            :fields="fields"
            :current-page="currentPage"
            :per-page="perPage"
            :stacked="true"
            small
            striped
            fixed
            hover/>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-pagination
            :total-rows="totalRows"
            :per-page="perPage"
            :number-of-pages="totalPages"
            v-model="currentPage"
            align="center"
          />
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
computed: {

    totalRows() {
      return {dynamic_udpate};
    },
    perPage() {
      return {dynamic_udpate};
    },
    currentPage: {
      get: function() {
         return {dynamic_udpate};
      },
      set: function (newPage) {
         {asyc_call_fetch_data_from_backend}
      }},
    totalPages() {
       return {dynamic_udpate};
    },
    items() {
      return {dynamic_udpate};
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Expectation:
Table content is updated dynamically when the data is refreshed after the backend call.

Actual result is:
When I click the page navigation except the 1st page, the container just show blank.
For vue debugger you can see the elements are the new fetched elements, id started from 6 since I set to present 5 items per page. Here's [a link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-57UR0Qpe75XKqNgs5MJ6fSWkEK2t9FS)!

If I go check the general page elements in Chrome debugger, the table content is empty. Here's [a link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FOoDHVl43gWfvgrXtKpyMcj0vcN6dvJl)!

Anyone gets an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you do not set `current-page` or `per-page` in the `b-table`?

Comment: @RoyJ thanks! I see the bug, there will always be one page available in my case.